# How do I optimize getting the result count when I just need to know if there is more than 1?

Tags: t-sql, count, query-optimization

I have a process that needs to know if there is exactly 1 match with various criteria on a table. I can get the count with a simple query but I expect I can optimize it since I don't care if there is 2 matches or 2000 matches. As soon as I know I have more than 1 the query can stop.

"TOP 2" won't work with "COUNT" since it only returns 1 result regardless of how many it counted. I don't have any indexes on the table I'm querying (and no control over that either), so I'm not expecting to be able to get better results using loops and cursors. A sub-query would do at least 1 full query too. Have I run out of options? Are custom aggregate functions something I should look into?

```sql
--Just a generic example. Only interested in knowing if @NumPerson = 1
DECLARE @NumPerson int
SELECT @NumPerson = COUNT(id) FROM Person 
WHERE vchLastName = <Last Name,varchar,> 
AND vchFirstName = <First Name,varchar,>
```

I'm not expecting huge gains, but we're using the query enough I want to make sure it's dialed in.

Comment: use EXISTS, it will perform better than count

Comment: @FLICKER `Exists` is more efficient than `Count` when checking for the existence of _one_ or more rows meeting some condition. How do you suggest using it to check for _two_ or more rows?

Comment: If `Person` has a _single_ index on `vchLastName` and `vchFirstName` then the desired rows should be quickly identified. If you query for `top (2) Id` and check [`@@RowCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) you'll have your answer: `0`, `1` or `2` (meaning two _or more_). It is one of the rare cases where `order by` doesn't matter.

Comment: Looks good! Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried a combination of exists, count(*) and having?

Comment: @HABO, the question is not very clear, otherwise I would post and answer. I guess I did not understand the question so your point is right..

Answer (score 0):

This will work - not sure about the performance of windowed functions:

> ;with cte as (
>
> SELECT    COUNT(id) over (partition by id order by id) as cnt,    id
>
> FROM Person
>
> ) select * from cte where cnt = 1